# Error when trying to add meteor-jade

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I'm surprised that I can not find anything regarding the error I am seeing... basically, when I do mrt add jade (https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade/), I get the following:

```
=> Errors while scanning packages:

While building package `jade`:
packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:126: HTML is not defined (compiling tests/tests.jade)
  at _.extend.visitTag (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:126)
  at _.extend.visitNode (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:90)
  at _.extend.visitBlock (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:74)
  at _.extend.visitNode (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:84)
  at _.extend.visitBlock (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:74)
  at _.extend.compile (packages/compileJade/plugin/compiler.js:21)
  at sourceHandler (packages/compileJade/plugin/handler.js:11)


While building plugin `compileJade` in package `jade`:
error: no such package: 'html-tools'
error: no such package: 'spacebars-compiler'
```

I did `mrt update` but still the same thing, any clue what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing:

```
meteor update --release blaze-rc0
```

As explained on the [`meteor-jade` github page](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade):

> Warning: This package is made for the new Meteor UI system, which is not released as a stable version yet. You'll need to run the `blaze-rc0` release.

I believe the next major release of Meteor (0.8 or 1.0) is supposed to include the stable release of Blaze UI. At that point, you should be able to just do:

```
meteor update
```

Comment: Meteor 0.8 includes the release of Blaze UI. A simple "meteor update" do the thing.

Comment: Ya, using 8.0 now, life is that much easier!!